# create a view windows in pycharm code like sublime text

Tags: python

I have a little question, I want to add to pycharm a window to look like sublime text
[the windows highlight in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DSMd.png)

does someone know how to add this in pycharm ?

Comment: The feature you are looking for is called *document map* (at least this is how they call it on notepad++) and after a quick search I didn't find it on pycharm..

Answer (score 0):

just found an answer , found at :
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7275-codeglance/